# Update Javascript variables on an interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I have a script that uses JSON data to create elements within a container div.  I have another script which updates the JSON data on a regular interval, but I'm having problems trying to get the new JSON data to auto-update in the created elements (without refreshing the page) using setInterval.

I am creating the variable like so:

```
function renderElement(ajaxResponse) {
var responseArray = JSON.parse(ajaxResponse);
var container = document.getElementById("container");
```

And then I use the JSON data to create my html like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < responseArray.length; i += 1) {

var element = document.createElement("div");
element.className = "element";
}

var Score = document.createElement("p");
Score.className = "Score";
Score.innerHTML = responseArray[i].Score;

element.appendChild(Score);
container.appendChild(element);

}
}
```

When I refresh the page, the data which was updated by the other script in the JSON does appear, however I'd like to make the new data appear without refreshing the page.  I've been trying to use setInterval to do this.  One problem I have is that the JSON data must be available on page load, and *then* update every 5 seconds, otherwise the broader script (isotope) will not draw itself.

After the replies below, I have placed the following in various parts of my code (within the function, after the function, etc).  The page loads, but I still cannot get the innerHTML elements to update as the JSON is updated (without refreshing the page):

```
setInterval(function() {renderElement(ajaxResponse); }, 5000);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

UPDATE:

I have changed it to:

```
setInterval(function() {renderElement(json); }, 5000);
```

So my ajaxResponse variable is being updated with the latest data, and then tried to add

```
setInterval(function() {renderElement(ajaxResponse); }, 10000);
```

within the function to update the innerHTML elements.  I *think* its working, as I can see multiple instances being drawn (behind the originals).  I'm now trying to "clear" the element div so when its updated, it doesn't keep the first set of data.

Comment: Your responseArray is an array variable and not a function, right? If so you cannot pass it as an arguement to setInterval. You need some function which deos the manipluation.

Comment: Your for loop does nothing, is it suppose to append the element?  Right now you create the variable element, and then it's lost when the for loop exits

Comment: You question is fully confusing. It's seems you have posted just some unusable parts of your codes.

Comment: @ryadavilli - I have updated my post with the complete function, sorry for the confusion

Comment: But responseArray is still a variable and not a function.

Comment: @Wolv3r  I have also tried setInterval with ajaxResponse function, but the page displayed nothing.  I believe its because the data isn't available when isotope is loading the page.

Comment: @Wolv3r Should I create another function that is within the ajaxResponse function that the setInterval refers to?

Comment: You could render the data you want on the server-side first, and then use `setInterval` to perform the updating afterwards.  See [What is the best way to pass server side variables to JavaScript on the client side?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598223/what-is-the-best-way-to-pass-server-side-variables-to-javascript-on-the-client-s)

Comment: It looks like you currently have the AJAX request fire off once and store it in an ajaxResponse variable that never gets updated. You need to pass setInterval a function that initiates an AJAX request. The renderElement function should be called when the response is received.

Comment: @PatrickMcElhaney I was doing just that when you must have commented. Thank you very much.  Please see my update above if you'd like to see my latest issue

Comment: Have a look at this question. I think it addresses what you're trying to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323240/setinterval-not-working-for-ajax-call/4323274#4323274

Answer (score 0):

You should call the renderElement function instead of ajaxResponse but to call a function with parameter within the setInterval you need to use `functon() { FuncHere() }`

Here's the complete code:

`setInterval(function() {renderElement(ajaxResponse); }, 5000);`

Comment: thank you very much - where should that code be placed?  When I place it on the line after `function renderElement(ajaxResponse) {` It takes 5 seconds to load the data, then loads the page, and doesn't appear to refresh the data if the JSON is changed/updated.  When I put it after the `function renderElement(ajaxResponse) {` function is closed, it loads immediatly as I'd like, but again doesn't appear to update the html as the JSON is changed.

Comment: the code can be placed at the top of all, but for the first call you need to write `rednerElement(ajaxResponse);` befor the setInterval function. And can you post your code where you get the ajaxResponse please?

Comment: I've been trying various iterations of your code in various places and still can't get it to work - just updating you...Usually, I get no errors, but the page appears to hang, and I need to force reload it.